# Does a Sefardi Yeshiva Bachur need to light his own Chanukkiyah?

Tags: halacha, chanuka, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, yeshiva-school

In Yeshiva does a Sefardi Bachur need to light their own personal Chanukkiyah or can they rely on their father lighting? And if they can rely, can one light one anyway?

Comment: In yeshiva, the Sfardi boys would not light, but would stand next to the Ashkenazi boys to hear the Brachos and see the lights. This was done through guidance of their rabbis, but I don't have names so I won't post this as an answer.